# How We Can Change Objects Position With Animation On Game Maker?

Tags: animation, move, game-maker, gml

I want to code an object that, when the left mouse button it pressed on it, starts moving towards (x,y) point and when it reaches the (x,y) point it stops moving.
I order to object when it's clicked by the left mouse button. The object moves towards (x,y) with 75 px/s speed but it doesn't stop at (x,y) point, it keeps moving on.

Comment: you need to add your efforts and explain in detail what you want to do

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

Create Event:

```
moving = false;
moving_speed = 4;

target_x = 0;
target_y = 0;
```

Global Mouse Left Pressed Event:

```
target_x = mouse_x;
target_y = mouse_y;
moving = true;

sprite_index = spr_walk; // Start animation
image_speed = 0.5; // Animation speed
```

Step Event:

```
if moving and point_distance(x, y, target_x, target_y) > moving_speed 
{
    dir = point_direction(x, y, target_x, target_y);
    x += lengthdir_x(moving_speed, dir);
    y += lengthdir_y(moving_speed, dir);
}
else
{
    moving = false;
    x = target_x;
    y = target_y;
    image_speed = 0; // Stop animation
    sprite_index = spr_stay;
}
```